# Problem of separation of variables for Dirichlet boundary data of Laplace's equation in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, dirichlet-series, partial-differential-equations

[image]

Need help here with figuring out boundary conditions for this problem. Also, for (i), I do know a general way or method but here I am confused since from both equations how do I find out my desired result?

Also, it says $u(x) = v(r)w(*)$, (*----I dont know what's this and which syntax you use to define it on latex).

this equation doesnt make sense to me since it should be such that you can take 1st and 2nd partial derivatives of it but here how do I take it? Maybe its $x$ is a function of $r$ and the other variable but its not mentioned in the problem.

I came up with a solution which I think looks correct but it doesn't match with whatever is expected in (i).

[image]
[image]
[image]

It would be great if someone helps me on this. Appreciate your help & support.

Answer (score 1):

The construction $u(x)=v(r)w(\theta)$ is an *ansatz*, an educated guess. There's no a priori reason for it, and depending on the boundary conditions the solution to the equation might not have this form.

However, it is very useful as a building block for the general solution to the problem. The variable $x$ is simply a short-hand for the pair $r$ and $\theta$.

Hint: Use the *ansatz* to express the partial derivatives as total derivatives of $v$ and $w$, then put everything that depends on $r$ on the LHS, and everything that depends on $\theta$ on the RHS. What can be said about the value these functions are equal to?

Comment: well this is the technique or method called separation of variables. however, I am trying to use your hint to get (i) first. that is where I am facing a problem. it wud be great if u help me on this.

Comment: @felipe......pls check my solutions I posted, there $w($\ansatz$)$ actually looks like $\gamma$ but its not. Also, I tried doing it but I am not getting the desired result which is given in (i).

Comment: You made some good progress. This next part is indeed tricky. Notice that you have a boundary condition on $\theta$. As you noticed at the end, you have to guarantee periodicity, $w(0)=w(2\pi)$ and $w'(0)=w'(2\pi)$. If the constant $\lambda$ you introduced was negative, could you satisfy these with a nonzero solution?

Comment: Also, in (ii), take a more careful look at the problem statement. You have to guarantee that the solution does not blow up at $r \to 0$. What does this imply about the exponents $k$ in $r^k$?

Comment: @Felipe.....I tried doing as u said with the Boundary conditions on $\theta$ and the one's you mentioned. I cant get the solution, I am able to check and get $w(0) = w(2\pi)$ and $w'(0) = w'(2\pi)$. I got one as $A_n$ and the other one as $kB_n$ respectively. even if I plug in k as $\lambda^{2}$, then also I dont get the desired result.